# How can I string together different objects in PHP

Tags: php

I want to have a string all connect together so I can just echo one defined group. I thought this might work.

```
$randomnum = rand(500000,600000);
$refnum = (echo 'ST' . $randomnum . '-' . $coupon_id . '-' . $userid . '');
$refnum;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You can't assign `echo` to a variable like that.

```
$randomnum = rand(500000,600000);
$refnum = 'ST' . $randomnum . '-' . $coupon_id . '-' . $userid . '';
echo $refnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$refnum = 'ST' . $randomnum . '-' . $coupon_id . '-' . $userid;
```